# Spring PropertyPlaceHolder Java Config external properties file

Tags: java, spring, properties, classpath, spring-el

So this has to be some silly mistake, which I've not been able to pass through. I'm trying to externalize my properties file, currently placed in my user home. I'm loading the properties file using `@PropertySource` like this:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources(value = { @PropertySource("file:#{systemProperties['user.home']}/.invoice/config.properties") })
public class PropertiesConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertiesPlaceHolderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

But unfortunately, that is not loading the properties file. Throws `FileNotFoundException`. But if I change the path to:

```
@PropertySources(value = { @PropertySource("file:/home/rohit/.invoice/config.properties") })
```

it works properly. And that is the path which the earlier path resolves to. I've logged it to verify. So it seems to me that SpEL is not getting evaluated in the `@PropertySource` annotation. Is it supposed to work that way?

If yes, then is there any other way to read the external properties file, which sits in `/home/rohit`? I don't want to give absolute path, for obvious reasons. And I would like to avoid extending `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer` class.

One other option I tried was adding the `/home/rohit/.invoice` folder to tomcat classpath. But seems like Spring doesn't use System Classpath to resolve `classpath:` suffix. Any pointers on this?

Comment: The expression won't work use `file:${user.home}/.invoice/config.properties` instead.

Comment: @M.Deinum Let me try that..

Comment: @M.Deinum Ahaa!! It worked :) Post that as an answer, so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a `@PropertySoure` annotation EL expressions won't work. You are allowed to use placeholders `${...}` however that is also limited to system or environment variables. However as you want to resolve the home directory of the user you can use the `${user.home}` placeholder.

```
@PropertySource("file:${user.home}/.invoice/config.properties")
```

This should work as desired.